# Drupal 7 - node form - dsm/dpm does not work with own validate/submit function

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I want to add an own validation (or submit) handler/function to my existing node form. I tried multiply things (following), but it does not work properly.

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  $form['#validate'][] = 'MY_MODULE_handler';
//or
  $form['actions']['submit']['#validate'][] = 'MY_MODULE_handler';
//or
  $form['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MY_MODULE_handler';
//or
  $form['#submit'][] = 'MY_MODULE_handler';
//or
  array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'MY_MODULE_handler');
//or
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]='MY_MODULE_handler';
}
```

But none of these attempts seem to work with my handler:

```
function MY_MODULE_handler($form, &$form_state){
  dsm($form);  
  dsm($form_state);
}
```

Looking at the `$form` variable in `form_alter` I found that `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit']` and `$form['#validate']` have already a submit/validate handler.

But if I use one of the examples above, nothing is printed by `dsm`. In addition it does not print the confirmation (of submitting) anymore! But if I use

```
function MY_MODULE_handler($form, &$form_state){
  die('Handler was hit');
}
```

I see that the handler was hit.

What can be the reason? I need the handler to read two form fields and save them in one node attribute.

Comment: `$form['#validate'][] = 'MY_MODULE_handler';` should work. Just because the dsm is not printing to the page, does not mean your function isn't called. Try adding `form_set_error('element', 'Handler was hit"');` in your validation function to see if it's called.

Comment: @2pha, thanks for your response. Yes, that was also my impression that the handler was called (since `die('...')` worked). But I still need the output (the confirmation printout which was there before and the printout of the variables) in order to move on. Any suggestions why they do not work anymore?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @2pha, Ok, the main idea is that I added in my `form_alter` two tableselect fields to my form. In the custom validation function I want to assign the values of both tableselect to one node property I created in the backend. This property also has an own field in the form (checkboxes, which is hidden). Might be a bit circuitous, if you have other ideas - I am open minded. ;)

Nevertheless, I expected it to work that way...

Comment: Just validate data in the validation function, find another hook to combine the values. eg. [HOOK_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x)

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot. I think this hook will do the job. In addition it prints my messages and `dsm()` again. I will close this thread later, when I have implemented it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @2pha proposed, I used instead of an additional validation/submit handler the hook [HOOK_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x) which allowed me to solve my problem (which was to assign values from the form to one node attribute, see comments).